# PRIMARY KEY must be unique error (Django)

Tags: python, django, view, primary-key

->'views.py':

```
def upload_event_image(request):
  if request.method=="POST":
    if request.FILES:
      fest=get_object_or_404(Fest, pk=request.POST.get('fest_pk'))
      if fest is not None:
        event = Event.objects.create(
          author = request.user,
          fest = fest,
        )
        event.save()
        if event:
          photo= Photo.objects.create(
            image = request.FILES['file'],
            album = event //This line causes the error
          )
          photo.save()
        return HttpResponse()
  return HttpResponse()
```

-> model.py:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank = True)
    fest = models.ForeignKey(Fest)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description

    def has_upvoted(self, user):
        return user

class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60 , blank= True, null = True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='site-media/media/images/')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="site-media/media/images/thumbs/", blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="site-media/media/images/thumbs2/", blank=True, null=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

When i make a post to the above view i get '**PRIMARY KEY must be unique'**. What am i doing wrong? 
This is the line **"album = event"** which causes the error.

Final solution after correction:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, **kwargs):
    """Save image dimensions."""
    super(Photo, self).save(force_insert, force_update, **kwargs)
    im = PImage.open(pjoin(MEDIA_ROOT, self.image.name))
    self.width, self.height = im.size

    self.create_thumbnail()
    force_insert = False
    force_update = True

    super(Photo, self).save(force_insert, force_update, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Do you have auto-increment set on your primary key field?

Comment: Its there by default right?

Comment: It would be wise to check. Also see this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/ALDujJRr0Ko

Comment: I haven't set any field as the primary key, as you can see above. So, it has django's default auto-incrementing field as the primary key.

Comment: Did you insert `Photo` objects with a specified primary key before? I recently had the case where I filled the table with existing data including primary keys in a south data migration, and the SEQUENCE did not get incremented. If you are using PostgreSQL, you can inspect the sequence with `\d app_model_id_seq` in a SQL shell.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that should raise such an error, so your problem is very likely somewhere in your database - either what sk1p said or your db table is not in sync with your model.

Comment: Also and just for the record: 1/ `get_object_or_404()` raises an `Http404` error if the objet is not found so the `if fest is no None` test is useless, 2/ `Queryset.create()` do save the created instance to the database so the `event.save()` and `photo.save()` calls and the `if event` test are useless too.

Comment: Oh and yes : it's not the 'album = event' line that causes the error but the whole `Photo.objects.create` statement. Also are you sure you want to actually _create_ an `Event` here ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers 'album' field must be an event instance. So, for that i have created an 'Event'.

Comment: Also, both the objects get created successfully but it still shows error.

Comment: @Monique: I know how to read a Django model ;). The point here is that you are creating a _new_ Event (with no title nor description) for each image upload, when you can have as many images you want per event. Don't you think you'd want to pass an `event_id` in your `request.POST` (like you did for the `Fest`) ?

Comment: Please post the full traceback - and inspect you db like sk1p suggested.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Fest object is created already. That's why i'm passing it. A fest can have many events. Then events can be of 2 types : one with a description and the other type with images from the 'Photo' model. I don't know how else can I get this done.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43756/discussion-between-bruno-desthuilliers-and-monique)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From chat with Monique: the problem is in the (non-posted) `Photo.save()` method that makes two calls to `super().save()`, *passing the same args in both cases*, so the first call correctly creates the `Photo` instance and the second tries to insert it again, which obviously fails.

Solution (for anyone having the same problem): **dont** blindly pass `*args` and `**kwargs` to `Model.save()` when your overload it and end up calling it a second time.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).save(force_insert, force_update, **kargs)
        if somethings_needs_to_be_done:
            do_something_here()
            super(Foo, self).save(force_insert=False, force_update=True, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Here is the fixed save():                                           def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, **kwargs):
        """Save image dimensions."""
        super(Photo, self).save(force_insert, force_update, **kwargs)
        im = PImage.open(pjoin(MEDIA_ROOT, self.image.name))
        self.width, self.height = im.size

        self.create_thumbnail()
        force_insert = False
        force_update = True

        super(Photo, self).save(force_insert, force_update, **kwargs)

Comment: @Monique : please edit your original post and put this in - the comment destroys all formatting ;)